# Within "gulp test" Reporter: "html" do not response, although I have inserted htmlreporter block

Tags: node.js, gulp, karma-jasmine

Habedere (a common bavarian greet),
my problem is now, that the karma html reporter don't work.
We use NodeJS so I updated like this "npm update -g".
When I type in "gulp test" everyhing turns out like expected, but the html report is not generated.

Code snippets below

karma.conf.js

```
plugins : [
      'karma-chrome-launcher',
        'karma-teamcity-reporter',
        'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
        'karma-html-reporter',
      'karma-angular-filesort',
      'karma-coverage',
      'karma-jasmine',
      'karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor'
    ],

    // the default configuration
        htmlReporter: {
          outputDir: 'karma_html/', // where to put the reports
          templatePath: null, // set if you moved jasmine_template.html
          focusOnFailures: true, // reports show failures on start
          namedFiles: false, // name files instead of creating sub-directories
          pageTitle: null, // page title for reports; browser info by default
          urlFriendlyName: false, // simply replaces spaces with _ for files/dirs
          reportName: 'report-summary-filename', // report summary filename; browser info by default
        },

        reporters: ['progress', 'html', 'coverage', 'teamcity'],
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "gimliPrototyp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "karma-html-reporter": "^0.2.7"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "gulp test"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "~2.9.11",
    "browser-sync-spa": "~1.0.3",
    "chalk": "~1.1.1",
    "del": "~2.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-angular": "~0.12.0",
    "estraverse": "~4.1.0",
    "gulp": "~3.9.0",
    "gulp-angular-filesort": "~1.1.1",
    "gulp-angular-templatecache": "~1.8.0",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "~3.0.2",
    "gulp-eslint": "~1.0.0",
    "gulp-filter": "~3.0.1",
    "gulp-flatten": "~0.2.0",
    "gulp-inject": "~3.0.0",
    "gulp-jasmine": "^2.3.0",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "~0.10.0",
    "gulp-minify-css": "~1.2.1",
    "gulp-minify-html": "~1.0.4",
    "gulp-ng-annotate": "~1.1.0",
    "gulp-protractor": "~1.0.0",
    "gulp-rename": "~1.2.2",
    "gulp-replace": "~0.5.4",
    "gulp-rev": "~6.0.1",
    "gulp-rev-replace": "~0.4.2",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-size": "~2.0.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "~1.6.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "~1.4.1",
    "gulp-useref": "~1.3.0",
    "gulp-util": "~3.0.6",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "~0.9.0",
    "json-server": "^0.8.8",
    "karma": "^0.13.22",
    "karma-angular-filesort": "~1.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage": "~0.5.2",
    "karma-html-reporter": "^0.2.7",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.8",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor": "~0.2.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "~0.2.1",
    "karma-teamcity-reporter": "^1.0.0",
    "lodash": "^3.10.1",
    "main-bower-files": "~2.9.0",
    "node-sass": "^3.4.2",
    "phantomjs": "~1.9.18",
    "uglify-save-license": "~0.4.1",
    "wiredep": "~2.2.2",
    "wrench": "~1.5.8"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.0"
  }
}
```

---